# What are the typical research requirements for an application to lecturer position to be successful?

Tags: publications, citations, professorship

When someone is applying for a position as a lecture at an average ranking university in Sweden (equivalent to associate professor elsewhere), what is the typical number of research papers and of what quality he is expected to have in order to have a realistic chance of getting the position?

Comment: "Lecturer" in the United States is very different from "Lecturer" in the U.K.  Can you let us know, preferably by editing or tagging the question, in what country you are applying?

Comment: I meant a lecturer position from a European university.

Comment: The research track record is only one parameters among many, and it's not the most important one. Even if it was, there are so many differences between different fields, institutions.

Comment: Do you think its possible for someone with only a Phd and only one paper at an A* conference (but several papers at A* conference workshops) and teaching/mentoring experience to get a lecturer position in Sweden(its also called associate prof btw)?

Comment: In theory everything is possible, it depends how competitive the specific position is. If you can find out information about past similar positions in similar institutions that could give you an indication (also the profile of the accepted candidate). In general I'd say it's likely that these positions are very competitive, with hundreds of applicants, some probably having more experience than you. But it would also depend a lot on your research project and how well it fits with the particular research group.

Answer (score 1):

The skills to teach are more important than a list of papers...

Having had to suffer "good" researchers who proved to be poor at explaining things, then the focus should be on the lecturing ...

Comment: The positions seem to  list research as the most important requirement. What is the typical number of applicants that you have seen at these positions?

Comment: Pick a number greater or equal to zero... Really that is not answerable... some positions may get hundreds of applicants, others one or two... just depends on **so** many factors : location, subject, salary...

Comment: Think about the factors I mentioned and the others... Such as who you may be working with...

Comment: Since OP clarified this is in Europe, and based on the comments, this does not seem to be a primarily teaching position.

Comment: @BryanKrause Tge OP stated that it was a “lecturing position” unless you know different and it is a research post?

Comment: For example in the UK a "lecturer" is what would be called an assistant professor in the US. OP stated in a comment that research was listed as the most important requirement which is consistent with that type of position rather than the "primarily teaching" implication of the title in the US.

Comment: I agree "lecturing" vs "lecturer" makes it a bit unclear but I think the former was just a mistake, the title and context suggest lecturer.

Comment: I am specifically interested for a lecturer(associate prof) in Sweden.

Comment: Edited question to include "Sweden" and "associate prof".  Please double-check that I haven't hanged your meaning, and edit the question to clarify if I have.